# Determine tcp connection state

Tags: sockets, tcp, state

In linux, how can i determine the state of a TCP socket?
I searched many in this theme, but i does not finded real usable solution.
I the most chases says: write something into the socket and it will fail if connection closed.
But what if the content of stream is bound, and a may not write anything junk into the stream?
I a other aspect the netstat can determine the socket state, but if i would like to implement the netstat based solution, it will be very expensive. I must resolv the fileDescriptor to socketID, than read all record from /proc/net/tcp, find the fitting line and test state is established. It is not so efficient if this method must be periodically called.
It there some other shorthand solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. TCP sockets don't have dynamic state; they only have the result of prior operations. If you don't operate on a TCP connection, it is deliberately designed not to change state. It has no 'dial tone', and this is a fundamental reason why it has completely replaced network architectures like SNA that did.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform a socket I/O operation to determine if the connection is still alive.  If you cannot write to the socket, you can still attempt a read operation instead (as long as it does not interfere with any other read operations) and see if it fails with a connection error.

Comment: ... bearing in mind that reading doesn't expose network problems the way write does.

Comment: Writing isn't guaranteed to expose them, either. Until the socket knows the connection has been disconnected/lost, it will happily keep accepting outbound data into its internal buffer until it eventually fills up, then it will block the caller from further writes until the disconnect is eventually detected, causing writes to fail. Same thing with reading. When the socket's internal buffer is empty, there will be no more data to read, blocking the caller from reads, but eventually the socket will detect the disconnect, causing reads to fail.

Comment: It's not the same. Writing forces the stack to send data, expect ACKs, send retries, operate retry timers and counters, ... all of which can eventually trip a failure condition. Reading just reads. The only failure condition is a read timeout, and that only goes to the application, without tripping anything permanent in the stack.

Comment: Reads may not do everything that writes do, but if the socket state has already been flagged after a connection failure was detected, even if no writes occur the OS can still receive resets and timeouts and such and flag the socket, so reads can and do report failures as well. I know, because I use that feature in my own code. The OS will not allow a read from a dead socket if it knows the socket is dead.

Comment: The point is that reading doesn't do anything that could detect or induce a connection failure. Only writing does that. If the socket isn't writing, there is nothing to timeout, and no reason for the peer to send resets.

Comment: You can enable TCP keep-alives to handle that.

Comment: You can indeed, noting that TCP keep-alive is (a) off by default and (b) has a default timeout of two hours.

Comment: @EJP: on some platforms, there are APIs to customize the keep alive intervals on a per-connection basis.